# Rails 3 undefined method in_groups_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use in_groups_of method but I'm getting an undefined method error

view:

```
<% @article_list.in_groups_of(4, false) do |category, article_items| %>
  <h3><%= category %></h3> 
  <% article_items.last(5).each do |article_item| %>
    <p><%= link_to article_item.name, account_article_path(article_item.account, article_item) %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.includes(:account, :category)
    @article_list = @articles.group_by { |t| t.category.name }
  end
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of @article_list? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

`in_groups_of` is a method of `Array` class.
Make sure that `@article_list` is an Array.

Comment: thats the problem. I just added my controller code to my question. The way I have it returns a hash. How would I change this?. Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to rails.